# WPF cut controls that goes outside the grid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm learning C# and WPF. I need to put a form with some `Image` on a face of a 3D cube (the cube is defined in a `Viewport3D`) using the `Viewport3DVisual3D` control.

I defined the `Visual` element of the `Viewport3DVisual3D` as a `Grid`. I defined the grid dimensions equal to the dimension of the cube's face. I added the images as children of the grid:

[image]

How can I position the images to the desired (x,y) on the grid?
I tried with the `Margin` propriety of the `Image`, as example:

```
        Image im = new Image();
        im.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("panotec.png"));
        im.Width = 0.5;
        im.Margin = new Thickness(-6, -0.5, 0, 0);
```

But when the image goes out form the area defined by the grid dymension the whole grid is compressed to fit the cube's face surface. as in the image:

[image]

How can I prevent it? I want that the parts of the controls that are outside just being cropped. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is really simple:

```
myGrid.ClipToBounds = true;
```

Also moved from `Grid` to `Canvas` for better position the images:

```
Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
Image im = new Image(...);
Canvas.SetTop(im, top);
Canvas.SetLeft(im, left);
myCanvas.Children.Add(im);
```

Comment: you should accept your answer as an answer : )  it helped me thanks